# Problem: Bing Imagesarch API returns image urls. Using ImageIO.read(url) to read returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, json, url, javax.imageio, bing-api

I´m using the Bing image search API on Netbeans java 8. I obtained the JSON data correctly, about 263 matches. Every match has its data on a "value" key, and each image is stored in "contentUrl" key.

For example:

- value

  - contentUrl="http://www.example.com/images/cake-chocolate.jpg"
- value

  - contentUrl="https://www.example2.com/images/chocolatecake.png"
    ...etc

I obtain the contentUrl as a String, then convert it using URL as the following example code:

```
String firstMatch = (String) firstMatch.get("contentUrl");
URL url1 = new URL(firstMatch);
Image cakePic = ImageIO.read(url1);
ImageIcon cakeIcon = new ImageIcon(cakePic);
```

Now the problems:

On my first 3 image matches, or "contentUrl" urls, I can only obtain and show the first match. The second and third throw a null pointer exception as follows:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

I printed the URL variables on system.out, of my own testing. I used the query "delicious salads anne wilson" (translated from spanish). I pasted those URLs on Firefox and the images showed no problems.

Of these first 3 matches, I can only load the 1st match. 2nd and 3rd throw null pointer exception. I tried each match alone and still getting null pointer exception.

http://globedia.com/imagenes/noticias/2011/12/17/deliciosas-ensaladas-anne-wilson_1_1014200.jpg

http://librosgratisxd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/deliciosas-ensaladas-de-anne-wilson2.jpg

http://librosgratisxd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/deliciosas-recetas-de-carne-picada-de-anne-wilson-150x150.jpg

I´m suspecting that ImageIO.read(URL) is missing something that the server needs. Maybe an useragent? a referer? I tried other of the 263 matches and some work and others don´t. Please help!

EDIT: added the second image match JSON data. This one throws a null pointer exception.

```
"webSearchUrl":"https:\/\/www.bing.com\/images\/search?view=detailv2&FORM=OIIRPO&q=Deliciosas+ensaladas+-+Anne+Wilson.pdf&id=3BFE78A6DEFEEF3854FED2B49A902EC885D1037C&simid=607995057971464317",
     "name":"Deliciosas ensaladas ( Anne Wilson)",
     "thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/tse3.mm.bing.net\/th?id=OIP.cB5jsoePgzfSdxEf8kDIUQDJEs&pid=Api",
     "datePublished":"2012-01-08T05:52:00.0000000Z",
     "isFamilyFriendly":true,
     "contentUrl":"http:\/\/globedia.com\/imagenes\/noticias\/2011\/12\/17\/deliciosas-ensaladas-anne-wilson_1_1014200.jpg",
     "hostPageUrl":"http:\/\/globedia.com\/deliciosas-ensaladas-anne-wilson",
     "contentSize":"114736 B",
     "encodingFormat":"jpeg",
     "hostPageDisplayUrl":"globedia.com\/deliciosas-ensaladas-anne-wilson",
     "width":344,
     "height":512,
     "hostPageFavIconUrl":"https:\/\/www.bing.com\/th?id=AR_6305881f91324e69f0fc25409f3f15c0&pid=Api",
     "thumbnail":{
        "width":204,
        "height":304
     },
     "imageInsightsToken":"ccid_cB5jsoeP*mid_3BFE78A6DEFEEF3854FED2B49A902EC885D1037C*simid_607995057971464317*thid_OIP.cB5jsoePgzfSdxEf8kDIUQDJEs",
     "insightsMetadata":{
        "pagesIncludingCount":6,
        "availableSizesCount":4
     },
     "imageId":"3BFE78A6DEFEEF3854FED2B49A902EC885D1037C",
     "accentColor":"A33E28"
  }
```

EDIT 2: I tried using apache commons IO library, and used the

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);

The file written was an html file with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://librosgratisxd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/deliciosas-ensaladas-de-anne-wilson2.jpg">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Basically, its the same url but with "https" on the front. Damn.

Comment: well you `contentUrl` value is missing `http://` or `https://` for you to connect and download... and your browser will automatically assume `http://` before any URL you use inside it

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Bing includes "http://" or "https://". See the JSON data posted. That is the 2nd image match, which fails to load with ImageIO

Comment: While using `ImageIO.read(URL)` does work for very basic stuff like a plain HTTP GET, it may be easier/more intuitive to work with a more sophisticated HTTP client library to deal with "real" network requests (ie. handling redirects like above, caching, etc). It's also a much better separation of concerns, separating the image decoding logic from the network handling logic.

Comment: @Martincho, have you fixed your problem? What is the solution?

Comment: Yes! I had to hardcode due to time constraints. I simply edited the obtained string from "http" to "https", and it worked for about 8-10 testings. Of course this doesn´t cover all url redirections, but for evaluation purposes, it did fine. Thanks for asking!